# What color is a puppy's accident?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across this sentence:

> We stepped into a windowless, off-white waiting room carpeted in shag **the color of a puppy's accident**.

Now, I've never been in an accident involving a puppy. So, can anyone tell me what exactly is the color of "a puppy's accident"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of raising a dog is training it to not urinate or defecate in the house.

When a puppy has an "accident" it means they've done one of these two things inside rather than telling their owner they they need to go out and use the toilet.

So, this sentence is saying that the rug was a rather gross color... either the color of urine or excrement. If I had to bet, I'd guess it was urine.

This image is from a lovely article on [PetMD.com](http://www.petmd.com/dog/puppycenter/potty-training/evr_dg_how_to_prevent_puppy_accidents) about how to house train a puppy.

[image: Puppy had an accident]